# Openlayers Overlay autopan doesn't work when map width is not 100%

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6

Openlayers version: v6.

Overlay autopan is not able to move the map to display the entire pop-up window when the map container width is not 100% to the viewport(click at the right end of the map).

In the screenshots below, I set the map width as 60%. When clicking on the right side of the map, the map didn't move as expected to display all the contents of the pop-up window.

I don't want to display the map to 100% viewport because I'd like to show another component on the right side.

The autopan only works when the map width is 100%. In this case, if I clicked the right side, the map displayed entire pop-up window.

**To reproduce this problem**, visit the [example here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html) and change the map width smaller than the viewport, then click on the right side of the map.

**How to make the autopan work on the right side when map width is smaller than viewport?**

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: That does not happen when the map opens at 60% width.  If you programmatically change the map div size after the map has opened you must call `map.updateSize()`.

Comment: Hi @Mike, thank you. Your comment is right. If you can answer the question, I will accept it.